# Elasticsearch: Autocomplete search with spaces example not working

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, whitespace, n-gram

**The goal:**

If I have a document with title `The Hitchhikers Guide`, the following searches would bring up that document:

- `hitch`
- `the hit`
- `hitchhikers gu`

The following searches would NOT bring up that document:

- `hiker`
- `uid`
- `guide th`

I'm following this article:  https://medium.com/@davedash/writing-a-space-ignoring-autocompleter-with-elasticsearch-6c3c28e3a974

But I can't seem to get the expected results in the indexing/analysis step.  I tried this on ES 5.3 and 6.3.

**Here's what I have so far:**

My mapping:

*PUT my_test*

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "index":{
            "analysis":{
                "filter": {
                    "autocomplete_filter": {
                        "type": "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram": "1",
                        "max_gram": "30"
                    },
                    "autocomplete_word_joiner": {
                        "type": "word_delimiter",
                        "catenate_all": true
                    }
                },
                "analyzer":{
                    "product_name_autocomplete_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "autocomplete_word_joiner",
                            "autocomplete_filter"
                        ]   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "doc" : {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text", 
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "product_name_autocomplete_analyzer",
                    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then testing the analyzer:

*POST my_test/_analyze*

```
{
  "analyzer": "product_name_autocomplete_analyzer",
  "text": "the hitchhikers guide"
}
```

Here are the tokens:

```
t
th
the
theh
thehi
thehit
...
thehitchikersguid
thehitchikersguide
h
hi
hit
hitc
hitch
...
hitchiker
hitchikers
g
gu
...
guide
```

This is unexpected because it is missing `hitchhikersg`, `hitchhikersgu` etc

This means that a search on `hitchhikers gu` fails, which is what I am seeing.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't think your `autocomplete_word_joiner` is doing quite what you think it is doing. The tokens it creates would be `["the", "thehitchhikersguide", "hitchhikers", "guide"]`.

Comment: Right.  I was hoping it would additionally  create `"thehitchhikers"` and  `"hitchhikersguide"`.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful to you, but often times `stopwords` will be removed. Such as `"the"`. If you included a `stopword` filter, you would get more matches in this particular use case. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html